# Google Cloud Storage vs SFTP

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, sftp

We have a new ThirdParty File Based Integration coming for one of our projects. Its a different company that puts a file and we would need to grab the file and continue processing. We need this file needs to be transfered securely. So First Option that comes is SFTP however we are thinking of doing a research on SFTP vs Google Cloud Storage. Can Google Cloud Storage be used instead of SFTP ? what are the pros and cons of the same.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are concerned about security in GCS, it has acl with which you can control the access to GCS

Comment: ok Thanks @LakshmanDiwaakar , will look into it.

Comment: @LeoPrince which method did you used is it sftp or GCS

Comment: @Hans It's been a while, I vaguely remember we used GCS. I think both SFTP and GCS can be used, it depends much on your infra teams guidance.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different sorts of things. Google Cloud Storage is a service that stores files. SFTP is a protocol for transferring files between two computers.

If your only goal is to transfer a file from computer A to computer B, and both can speak to each other via SFTP, then that's a perfectly good solution.

That said, services like GCS are commonly used as a drop box for large files as part of a distributed workflow. For instance, one service might record video and upload that video to GCS, and then another service might later transcode that video or take some other action on it. That's also perfectly reasonable.

So, I guess the answer is that it depends on what you want to do.